# Split string based on a table of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an SQL query in which I need to split string value based on a list of values existing in a reference table.

For example I have the string value "JOHN DOE SILVER" and the value "JOHN" is present in the reference table, I want to get "JOHN" as a result.

In the reference table, there is only one column with all values that can be found in the string.
The value is always at the beginning of the string.
I can have spaces in the value, for example :

**String** = "EXAMPLE STRING TEST"

**Value in reference table** = "EXAMPLE STRING"

**Result should be** = "EXAMPLE STRING"

I'm not sure how I can do that...
I think I first need to split the string based on "if the value at its begining is present in the reference table"... but I don't know how.

I hope it's clear enough so that somebody can help me on that !

**Edit** :

as it appears not to be clear enough, I try to specify.

In fact I need to populate a column in **my_table** with a value from the **reference_table** when it is found at the begnining of the 'test string' of my_table. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/1 for an attempt to test your answers

Notes :

- I can have similar values in the reference table and I need to take the longest ("CHEMIN RURAL" vs "CHEMIN" for example)
- If there is no value found then no value in the populated column (left join on my_table for example)
- the string to find is ALWAYS at the begining of the string in my_table

Answer (score 3):

You can use `INSTR` function in join as following:

```
Select r.str
  From your_table t
  Join ref_table r
    On INSTR(t.your_column,r.str) = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I gave it a try on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/1 but I have a problem, in the reference table I can have similar values so I get the lines duplicated when performing the join... (see CHEMIN and CHEMIN RURAL in the example)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in a join.

```
-- sample data
with my_table as (select 'EXAMPLE STRING TEST' as str_value from dual union select 'JOHN DOE SILVER' from dual),
     reference_table as (select 'EXAMPLE STRING' as str_value from dual union select 'JOHN' from dual)
-- query
select ref.str_value
from my_table m
join reference_table ref
  on m.str_value like ref.str_value || '%'
```

Comment: I gave it a try but as the answer from @Tejash I have a problem, in the reference table I can have similar values so I get the lines duplicated when performing the join... (see CHEMIN and CHEMIN RURAL in the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/1)

Answer (score 2):

The first problem I see is that you want 'Ruth' to match 'Ruth Miller', but not 'Ruthless John Brown'. I.e. the search string must either end the string or be followed by a space.

The second problem can be multiple matches, like 'John Bob Miller' found via 'John Bob' and 'John'. It suffices to show one match, i.e. the better (longer) string. Such ranking can be done with `ROW_NUMBER`.

With `LIKE`:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    t.*, r.typeref,
    row_number() over (partition by t.nom order by length(r.typeref) desc) as rn
  from test t
  left join reference_table r on t.nom = r.typeref or t.nom like r.typeref || ' %'
)
where rn = 1;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/52

With `REGEXP_LIKE` instead:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    t.*, r.typeref,
    row_number() over (partition by t.nom order by length(r.typeref) desc) as rn
  from test t
  left join reference_table r on regexp_like(t.nom, '^' || r.typeref || '[ $]')
)
where rn = 1;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/51

Comment: Hi, I always have a space as separator so your solution works as expected, with both `LIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below -

```
SELECT *
FROM REFERENCED_TABLE
WHERE 'EXAMPLE STRING' LIKE '%' || COLUMN_VALUES || '%'
```

Comment: OP most likely needs a solution with a join on the reference table

Comment: @Gandalf, It is nowhere mentioned in the question that he needs a join.

Comment: @ Ankit It is not explicitly mentioned, but I inferred it from "In the reference table, there is only one column"

Comment: Indeed I would need a join. I try to extract from my column in my_table a value at the begining if it is present in the ref_table. Not easy to explain... See sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/1

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You could achieve this using `window functions`

```
select distinct 
          t.*
         ,max(r.typeref) over (partition by t.nom order by length(r.typeref) desc) as typeref
from my_table t
left join reference_table r on instr(t.nom,r.typeref)=1;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60b0ca/8)**

Comment: Hi, I'm don't really understand what you're trying to do here. I don't need to select from the reference_table, I need to extract from my column in my_table a value at the begining if it is present in the ref_table.
Not easy to explain...

Comment: @Jeremie Your post says the result you need is the string value in the reference table if it matches the beginning of the the string value in my_table. Is that not the case? Are you bringing in other columns from my_table as well?

Comment: Sorry, it's not easy to explain it for me in english... I need to populate a column in my_table with a value from the reference_table when it is found at the begnining of the 'test string' of my_table. See sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbd72/1 for the example.
I edited to original post to add infos. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: @Jérémie Try my updated solution and see how that works

Comment: Thanks @Gandalf I will try this. unfortunately I have other emergencies to work on before.

Comment: I checked your solutions but it doesn't do what I want. For example, for CHEMIN BLEU, I should have CHEMIN as a result and not CHEMIN RURAL.
Therefore, I will choose @Thorsten Kettner solution as a valid solution. Thank you anyway for taking time to answer and all the details !

Comment: No worries. I update my solution so you can use it as reference